# Replacement has less rows than data - How can I solve this error?

Tags: r, function, truncate

## Truncated version of the data

```
 truncate1 <- function(x) { 
 qs <- quantile(x, c(.01, 0.99)) 
 trimx <- x[x > qs[1] & x < qs[2]] 
 return(trimx)
  }
```

## Truncation version of the data

```
TRU_BANK <- as.data.frame(BANK)
```

## Winsorization of the independent variables to control for outlier

```
 TRU_BANK$TVAR_AVG <- truncate1(TRU_BANK$TVAR_AVG) 
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TVAR_AVG", value = c(19.6, 35.2, 26.9,  : 
 replacement has 495 rows, data has 507
```

Comment: When you return a subset to field on a data frame that was not subset, you'll always get this error. This part of the function creates the subset `trimx <- x[x > qs[1] & x < qs[2]]`.  Can you write the function to take in the whole data set, subset the  data set, and return the new data set with the amended column?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to do that as well. How would I need to adjust it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend the function to subset the data frame rather than just a field; return the new data set.  Something reproducible:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(1,2,3,4,5), z = c(1,2,3,4,5))


truncate1 <- function(df, x) { 
  qs <- quantile(df[ ,x], c(.01, 0.99)) 
  trimx <- df[ df[ ,x] > qs[1] & df[ ,x] < qs[2], ] 
  return(trimx)
}
##putting the quotes around the column name or using a column number is key
new.df <- truncate1(df, "y")
```

new.df should be

```
 new.df
  y z
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

Comment: If I follow this method, I just get a now data frame with 507 rows and 0 columns...

Comment: Ok, well, I amended my example to show that the both columns come through on the dataframe.